# How to dynamically generate classes in SCSS from array?

Tags: sass

I have array of classes

$templates: (
  'one',
  'two',
  'three'
);

And I want to generate next code

```
input[type="radio"][id="one"]:checked {
  & ~ .two,
  & ~ .three {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
  }
}
input[type="radio"][id="two"]:checked {
  & ~ .one,
  & ~ .three {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
  }
}
input[type="radio"][id="three"]:checked {
  & ~ .one,
  & ~ .two {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
  }
}
```

What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I have next code

```
@mixin somemixinname {
    width:0;
    height:0;
}

@each $class1 in $templates {
    input[type="radio"][id="#{$class1}"]:checked {
        @each $class2 in $templates {
            @if $class2 != $class1 {
                &  ~ .#{$class2} { @include somemixinname }
            }
         }
    }
}
```

But It generates a bit different code(

Comment: Your code is correct with exception of `!==` that is not available in Sass, use `!=` instead. Generated code is equal to one that you want to get. Please notice that your desired code listed into question is not actually a CSS, but SCSS instead, however Sass generates CSS.

Comment: I desire to get css
input[type="radio"][id="one"]:checked ~ .two, input[type="radio"][id="one"]:checked ~ .three {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}
but my code generate styles for each class

Comment: There is no practical meaning for such desire because production style should be minified anyway and CSS minifier will most likely group these selectors for you.